# Angular web app Route not working on AWS Server

Tags: angular-cli

We are working on a Angular Project and are facing issues on Page Routing.

The issue is that when we try to manually open a page in the browser by typing the link directly, It shows "Cannot GET /url" page.

We have tried to solve this issue by changing the base-href value in the index.html file, Configure Route Fallback URL. But nothing seems to work.

We had some progress by using the "useHash strategy". But by using this method the logout functionality does not work. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqEZY.png)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Define "not working". Do you get a server-not-found? Page-not-found?

Comment: It shows page not found